# Logging every request to a certain file

Tags: apache, logging, httprequest, server, request-headers

I want to log all request- (and maybe also response-) headers of requests, that are made to a certain file on an Apache server. I have tried a php script, but that only fires when I request it directly. 
Is there any way to log all the requests on a file that I can specify? (If it does matter: in my case the file I want to log the requests for, is a mp4 file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set and environmental variable to use for determining logging behavior

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI /this/is/a/url.html$ thisurllog
CustomLog thisurl.log common env=thisurllog
CustomLog access.log common env=!thisurllog
```

The last line will prevent the entries for that URI from logging in common access log.  You can omit if you are OK with double logging into both logs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Do you, by any chance, know also a way to do this with PHP or the htaccess file?

Comment: Unfortunately `CustomLog` directive is only applicable in the server or virtual host context, so .htaccess is not an option.  I don't know where PHP would be an option here unless you want to configure Apache to use PHP as handler for mp4 files.  Without this, PHP would never be involved in serving a request for an mp4.  If you wanted to do this, once in PHP, you can write your own "log file" to your heart's content.